# Select All children after parent Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have data like this:

[image]

Now I want the result to look like the below, i.e., all the children rows come just after the parent row.

[image]

Please help me to produce the result like above attached image.

[sqlfiddle Data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b16295)

Comment: It looks like you just need to add `order by OrderId,ParentLimeItemId,DesignType` to the end of your query.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens or maybe `order by OrderId,ParentLimeItemId=0,DesignType` (or `order by OrderId,ParentLimeItemId<>0,DesignType`, never quite sure how booleans are sorted) to make sure the child rows get the same priority on the second level and so the sort order is guaranteed to be determined by `DesignType`?

Comment: Is there only one level to this parent/child relationship? Could there be another row (based on your sample data) with `ParentLineItemId` of 54, say?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yes there is only one level parent child relation. Basically all children comes just after Parent.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from tab
order by case when ParentLimeItemId = 0 then id else ParentLimeItemId end,
         id;
```

Comment: I want that all children comes just after Parent based with order by DesignType.

Comment: So can't you just add DesignType to the ORDER BY? I.e. order by case when ParentLimeItemId = 0 then id else ParentLimeItemId end, id, DesignType?